# Can I have training and test data in the same arff file?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, arff

I have an algorithm that accepts one file at a time. And I need it to learn rules from the training set and apply it on the test set. So if I include my test set right after my training set in the same file, would I be doing this correctly?

Currently I have it as

@data
....training set

@data
....test set

Comment: What does the ARFF file format specifation say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use Weka, in this case this not the 'right' way to do it. First create an ARFF file for training data. Then with same data structure (the structure you define in ARFF file which informs how the structured), create a test ARFF file.

In the training part, Weka will ask you to supply the training file, then you will have another option to supply test data, basically supply to test file. Simply this is the convention. You can put all your data in one file an you should be able to split it as well, but you might need to use Weka source code and might not be able to do it via explorer of Weka.

Comment: No I am not using Weka, Im using another an algorithm contained in a jar file that accepts one arff file at a time

Comment: Then we need details of that algorithm/software.

Comment: The algorithm is called Ant-Miner implemented by Parpinelli and can be found on SourceForge